# Reordering levels in stacked bar pplot in ggplot2, without count data

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using ggplot2 to produce a stacked barplot of mean values (not counts). This works fine with the following code:

```
new.stop <- read.delim("New_stop_data.txt")

A <- ggplot(new.stop, aes(x=Consonant, y=(Duration*1000), fill = Label)) + stat_summary(fun.y="mean", geom="bar") + coord_flip() + theme_bw() + ylab("Duration (ms)") + xlab("Stop")
A + scale_fill_grey()
```

Plotting things this way works fine, in principle and produces the following [plot](http://www.haskins.yale.edu/staff/dicanio/pdf/Data1.pdf). However, the order of the levels "vot" and "closure" should be reversed, with vot on the right. I have tried to fix this by using relevel() and, separately, factor(), as follows:

```
new.stop$Label <- relevel(new.stop$Label, ref="vot")
new.stop$Label <- factor(new.stop$Label, levels = c("vot", "closure"), labels=c("VOT", "Closure"))
```

However, this just produces a [barplot where both values are merged](http://www.haskins.yale.edu/staff/dicanio/pdf/Data2.pdf), as you can see. I've even tried to reorder within ggplot2, but to no avail. Since this data is not count data (and ggplot2 assumes you only will be using count data for barplots), I have been unable to find any help that seems to work here. Any help is much appreciated.

PS: For what I'm doing, barplots are typical.

Comment: Christian DiCanio try using `guides(... reverse = T)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a bit of Deep Magic when you start doing fancy stuff with stats.  Or at least, that's my benighted perspective. In any case, what works better is to:

1. Use geom_bar with the stat argument, rather than the other way around.
2. Put the aes(fill) inside the geom_bar(), rather than the ggplot() function.

There is some interesting stuff going on with the order in which things get aggregated.  Follow the above, and it works as expected initially, without a need for re-ordered of levels or anything:

```
ggplot(new.stop, aes(x=Consonant, y=(Duration*1000))) + geom_bar(stat="summary", fun.y = mean, aes(fill = Label)) + coord_flip() + theme_bw() + ylab("Duration (ms)") + xlab("Stop") + scale_fill_grey()
```

FWIW, this is why I personally tend to avoid stats.  I always get more predictable results when I do the data summaries first (with plyr or dplyr or something) and then ggplot the summary table.

Comment: Yes! This works. Thank you. Another colleague of mine just suggested just aggregating my data prior to plotting, which also seemed to work. So, one conclusion that we can reach on this is that the stat_summary() function does not let you reorder levels (at least not easily). So, all advice about reordering goes out the window if you are using this.

Comment: However, leaving in geom_bar(stat="summary", fun.y = mean, aes(fill = Label)) will result in very odd behavior if one attempts a facet_wrap(~Speaker). If one uses an aggregate function (as a friend suggested now), it works fine, e.g.
<p>
plotdata <- aggregate(Duration ~ Consonant + Label + Speaker, new.stop, mean)
A <- ggplot(plotdata, aes(Consonant, Duration*1000, fill=Label)) + geom_bar(stat="identity") + coord_flip() + theme_bw() + ylab("Duration (ms)") + xlab("Stop") + scale_fill_grey()
A + facet_wrap(~Speaker)

Answer (score 2):

Sorry. I edited my answer after accessing data provided by the user, a few hours latter.

from the data supplied, I'd first take a look on how it should be arranged, numerically.

dat <- read.delim(..\New_stop_data.txt)

```
head(subset(dat, select = c(Consonant, Label, Duration)))

  Consonant   Label    Duration
1       /p/ closure 0.127097695
2       /p/     vot 0.007426832
3       /p/ closure 0.128724749
4       /p/     vot 0.006942377
5       /p/ closure 0.116493725
6       /p/     vot 0.007421805
```

summarizing it to counts

```
ddply(dat, .(Consonant, Label), summarise, length(Duration*1000))

  Consonant   Label   D
1       /k/ closure 119
2       /k/     vot 119
3      /kw/ closure  75
4      /kw/     vot  75
5       /p/ closure 117
6       /p/     vot 117
7       /t/ closure 116
8       /t/     vot 116
```

plot counts

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x=Consonant), y=(Duration*1000)) + 
      geom_bar(aes(fill = Label), stat="bin") + 
      coord_flip() +
      theme_bw() + 
      labs(list = c(x="Duration (ms)", y='Stop')) +
      scale_fill_grey()+
      guides(fill = guide_legend(reverse = TRUE))
```

[image: counts]

and Means

```
ddply(dat, .(Consonant, Label), summarise, D = mean(Duration*1000))

  Consonant   Label         D
1       /k/ closure 108.35499
2       /k/     vot  26.52917
3      /kw/ closure 122.28891
4      /kw/     vot  31.46828
5       /p/ closure 135.90023
6       /p/     vot  11.27705
7       /t/ closure 124.73526
8       /t/     vot  16.91066

ggplot(dat, aes(x=Consonant, y=(Duration*1000))) + 
  geom_bar(stat="summary", fun.y = mean, aes(fill = Label)) + 
  coord_flip() + 
  theme_bw() + 
  labs(list(y="Duration (ms)", x='Stop')) +
  scale_fill_grey() +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(reverse = TRUE))
```

[image: means]

Comment: It's better to use [`TRUE` instead of `T`](http://www.r-bloggers.com/r-tip-avoid-using-t-and-f-as-synonyms-for-true-and-false/)

Comment: No, this doesn't work at all. It looks the same. If you'd like to try this yourself on my data set, it's here: http://www.haskins.yale.edu/staff/dicanio/pdf/New_stop_data.txt

Comment: Is this some issue with using stat_summary with barplots?